# Need help for Java UML about a class aggregated by itself

Tags: java, oop, uml

Hi I need some help about a java UML i have to implement.

This project is an introduction to Java OOP and UML, I don't know if it means anything out of context to you, but i don't get it :

[image]

I don't understand 2 things :

- It seems like this class has an instance of itself as a private static property (how should I instantiate it ? In the constructor ?)
- The constructor is private, and anyway I don't know what I should put inside it since the 2 properties are static anyway

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems like this class has an instance of itself as a private static property

this is visibly a singleton => only one instance memorized through that property

> (how should I instantiate it ? In the constructor ?)

it is instantiated the first time *getProvider* is called

> The constructor is private

of course, it must not be called from outside

> I don't know what I should put inside it since the 2 properties are static anyway

in any case *weatherProvider* must be set to memorize the alone instance, that can be done in the constructor or in *getProvider*, knowing the constructor is called when *weatherProvider* is null (default value)

Look at singleton implementation

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'm so grateful for your clear explanations ! I'm gonna check it out